# Inconvenientes con extensiones Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

Quiero instalar extensiones en VSC pero no me salen, ocurrio algun error durante la instalacion? tengo que configurar alguna variable? En todos los videos que solo dan click en extensiones y ya salen las recomendadas, a mi no me sale nada.
Tengo instalada la ultima version de VSC.
Por otro lado no veo errores en la consola de VSC y puedo crear y gestionar archivos Ok.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno ya investigando en otras fuentes detectamos que el market estaba caido, eso causó que VS Code no muestre ninguna extensión en el explorador de extensiones. Este problema fue rastreado en esta pagina: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57851.
Si alguno de ustedes tuvo el mismo inconveniente vuelvan a fijarse ya que esta solucionado, yo ya veo las extensiones